# How to store bcrypt salt with password_hash?

Tags: php

I'm using password_compat.php to use the password_hash and password_verify functions. I'm using the blowfish alogrithm. password_verify doesn't seem to be working though, it is not matching the stored hash in the database. Do I have to specify the algorithm or salt with password_verify?

reigster script:

```
            $hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $qry = "INSERT INTO users (email, fname, lname, gender, p4s5) VALUES ('$email', '$fname', '$lname', '$gender', '$hash')";
            $result = mysqli_query($dblink, $qry) or die(mysqli_error($dblink));
```

login script:

```
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($dblink, $qry);

        if (!mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // email not in database, error
            $loginErrors .= "<li>Username or password wrong</li>";
        } else {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            // verify password;
            $hash = $row["p4s5"];

            if (password_verify($pass, $hash)) {
                // not same, error
                $loginErrors .= "<li>Username or password wrong</li>";
            } else {
                // login user
                $id = $row["id"];
                $fname = $row["fname"];
                $lname = $row["lname"];

                login($id, $email, $fname, $lname);
                header("Location: ".$_SESSION["last-page"]);
            }
        }
```

Table structure:

CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUT...

Comment: What's your table structure? I.e. `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;`. If you're sticking with bcrypt you need at least 60 characters storage, with the default setting they recommend 255.

Comment: id  email  fname  lname  gender  p4s5

Comment: No, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;` and add the output in your question.

Comment: It doesn't output the full thing it's only giving me what I posted above.

Comment: Just use the standard mysql client.

Comment: What's that? I only have PHPMyAdmin access. I ran it using the "SQL" tab and only get that out.

Comment: Fine, then, how big is the `p4s5` column?

Comment: try to store in `blob`

Comment: It's a varchar size 128

Comment: Strange, 128 should be ample storage for bcrypt; try running `SELECT LENGTH(p4s5) FROM users;`

Comment: Then you just have to make sure `$pass` contains the expected value.

Comment: Okay I'll go through my code again

Answer (score 0):

Check your password length in your database this might be your problem.